# Cannot enable unity 3D effects on Alienware M14x

Tags: unity, nvidia, 3d

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed and updated on my Alienware M14x. I have the nVidia Geforce 555M proprietary driver installed.

But still I cannot enable the unity 3d effects. Please help me with this.

I guess its using my Sandy Bridge graphics unit for rendering the desktop. How do i get it to use my Nvidia GPU?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but on the forums someone described they were suffering from a similar issue with the same card. They said that they removed the Nvidia Drivers and then were able to use Unity/Compiz. Here's the link to the Forum Post http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11197162&postcount=7 .

Hope this helps.